# How to run rake command on Cloud66 Rails provisioning?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, cloud66

I have a Rails application that requires some rake tasks to be executed before starting the application. Is the a way to do this when deploying the application with Cloud66?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using [deploy hooks](http://help.cloud66.com/stack-features/deploy-hooks.html), which essentially allow you to take action at various points during the deployment process.

Alternatively, you could use the [rake task](http://help.cloud66.com/add-ins/rake-task.html) or [SSH command](http://help.cloud66.com/add-ins/shell.html) add-on to execute a one-off command through the UI.

Comment: Thanks. Deploy hooks worked fine, but is was not easy to identify which hook to use. My case:

* to install additional server components (postfix), I used first_thing hook

* to generate info need for the migrations, I used after_symlink

* to load initial data in the DB (seed), I used last_thing